# logical operators evaluation in return statement in python

Tags: python, logical-operators

How does this execute?

```
def f(x):
    return x>0 and (x%2)+f(x/2) or 0
```

`x` is an array, for instance: `[1, 1, 1, 3]`

Comment: It doesn't execute. You can't apply the modulus operator to a list and Python will tell you that with a TypeError exception.

Answer (score 2):

This code is broken. For starters, `x>0` is always true. But `x%2` and `x/2` yield type errors.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
$ python
Python 2.5.5 (r255:77872, Apr 21 2010, 08:40:04) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f(x):
...     return x>0 and (x%2)+f(x/2) or 0
... 
>>> f([1, 1, 1, 3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

evaluation in `return` statement is no different from evaluation in any other place. if `x` is a list this whole thing makes no sense and raises `TypeError`. `x` should be a numeric for this to work.

If `x` is a number it would work as follows:

- evaluate `x>0` statement
- if it was `True` return `(x%2)+f(x/2)` part. Which, of course, recurses infinitely
- if it was `False` return `0`

Answer (score 0):

The function recursively counts the number of 1's in the binary form of the number x.

Each time the function adds sums the lowest bit (either 1 or 0) with the bit count of a number without the last bit (dividing by 2 is like shifting right by 1), or with 0 if there are no more bits.

For example:
The function will return 2 for 5 as an input (5 is 101 in binary)
The function will return 3 for 13 as an input (13 is 1101 in binary)
...